# file encoding from any encoding to utf-8 in linux perl

Tags: linux, perl, encoding

I want to convert text file ip.txt 's encoding to US-ASCII regardless of whatever ip.txt's encoding.

When I am trying `raw:encoding(UTF-16LE)` error are coming as ***UTF-16LE:Partial character at script.perl line 10*** but when I am using

`raw:encoding(US-ASCII)` errors are like ***ascii "\xC0" does not map to Unicode at script.perl line 10.***

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $old= '/home/ip.txt';
my $new = '/home/out.txt';
open(my $myold, "<:raw:encoding(UTF-16LE):crlf:utf8", $old) or
die "Could not open file 1 $!";
open(my $mynew, ">>", $new) or
die "Could not open file 2 $!";
while( my $line = <$myold> )
{
    print {$mynew} $line;
}

close($myold);
close($mynew);
```

Please suggest how to use :raw:encoding():lf:utf8? What does it work, please explain it too?

Comment: If you are not sure of the encoding of `ip.txt`, you can try [Encode::Guess](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Guess)

Comment: Your title says "*to utf-8*". Your first sentence says "*to US-ASCII*". Which is it?

Comment: If you don't already know the encoding `ip.txt` is in, you have to guess. Depending on what it contains, such a guess might be impossible (or just uncertain). As for how to use *`:raw:encoding():lf:utf8`*: Why would I ever use that? It looks bizarre to me; I'd have to study the reference documentation or even the source code to find out what exactly it does. I would expect `<:encoding(FOO)` on `$myold` and `>>:encoding(BAR)` on `$mynew` (here `FOO` represents the source encoding, whatever that may turn out to be, and `BAR` the target encoding, either `UTF-8` or `US-ASCII`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like you're just guessing at the file's encoding. Seeing as there are 100s, that's not likely to be productive. To get rid of the errors, provide the actual encoding of the file.

---

> *When I am trying raw:encoding(UTF-16LE) error are coming as `UTF-16LE:Partial character at script.perl line 10`*

The file isn't encoded using UTF-16le.

> *when I am using `raw:encoding(US-ASCII)` errors are like `ascii "\xC0" does not map to Unicode at script.perl line 10.`*

The file isn't encoded using ASCII. (The input file contains byte `C0`, but the ASCII character set doesn't contain any such character.)

Comment: Yes you are right I was only guessing the encoding. Could you please tell me how to generalize it in perl ?

Comment: To be generic, you can use `"<:encoding($encoding)"`. But you still need to know the encoding.